# Taylor series proof

Tags: taylor-expansion

I would like to ask for some tips and  where can I find something to prove that:

$f''(x_0)= \frac{-f(x_0-3h)+4f(x_0-2h)-5f(x_0-h)+2f(x_0)}{h^2}+O(h^2)$

Thanks ${}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using second order Taylor-Lagrange formula, as $f''(x_0)$ exists, we can write

$$f(x_0-3h)=f(x_0)-3hf'(x_0)+\frac{9h^2}{2}f''(x_0)+O(h^3)$$

$$f(x_0-2h)=f(x_0)-2hf'(x_0)+\frac{4h^2}{2}f''(x_0)+O(h^3)$$

$$f(x_0-h)=f(x_0)-hf'(x_0)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x_0)+O(h^3)$$

$\implies$

$$-f(x_0-3h)+4f(x_0-2h)-5f(x0-h)+2f(x_0)=h^2f''(x_0)+O(h^3)$$

qed.

Comment: Isn't using Taylor-Lagrange formula requiring the function to be 2 times derivative in point $ x_0$  or is that information, given implicit by writing $f''(x_0)$ . I'm playing devil's advocate here.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am wondering if there is any function that if I apply the formula it will give an exact result without any error. I can only think in functions for example y=1.

Comment: I tried a couple of examples and it seems to work for all functions. Does it mean that this formula always works for all functions?

Comment: @user290335 No, it is just an aproximation. for example, it doesn't work for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: I understood. Thank you for your help.